# WebStorm: How to generate JSDoc documentation

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

I just started using WebStorm and JSDoc to document my JavaScript. Still I have not found a way to generate a HTML documentation using some kind of WebStorm built-in functionality. I searched the web and Stack Overflow, but only found a lot of questions about the syntax of JSDoc, etc.

What am I missing? I am using WebStorm 7.0.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice article about *jsDoc* for *phpStorm* at [this link](http://www.speich.net/articles/generate-javascript-documentation-with-jsdoc-3-and-phpstorm/).

In WebStorm I guess the same.

Comment: new link http://www.speich.net/articles/generate-javascript-documentation-with-jsdoc-3-and-phpstorm/

Comment: Updated article: https://www.speich.net/articles/en/2016/04/10/use-jsdoc-3-and-phpstorm-to-generate-javascript-documentation/

Answer (score 44):

Since *WebStorm* v8.0.0, you can create *JSDoc* comments by simply typing `/**` right before the `method` or `function` declaration you want to add the documentation, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This will generate a basic block with all your `parameters` already set.

More info on [this *WebStorm* article](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/creating-jsdoc-comments.html).

Comment: Why is this the most up-voted answer when it only applies to how to write the jsdoc source - *not* rendering documentation from the jsdoc, which is what the question is about?

Comment: @JHH because this is answering the question people who find this post actually have. I googled "How to automatically document JS code with JSDOC and WebStorm" and it took me here. The title is misleading because the original poster wants to make a page that shows the documentation. The actually documentation is the JSDOC though...

Answer (score 2):

WebStorm has no built-in functionality to generate documentation. You can use external solutions for that, at least as https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc

I use jsduck for that: https://github.com/senchalabs/jsduck

Answer (score 0):

WebStorm has a built-in function to help a little when creating JSDoc documentation in your code, they explain it in [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/creating-jsdoc-comments.html) article. As far as I could look for, there's no plugin on the WebStorm plugin store to further help us creating nor rendering JSDoc documentation. For that, you would need to use external tools.